# Pandas groupy "aggregate" does not see column

Tags: pandas

I am working on a huge database where I did a pandas apply to categorize the type of cliente based on the type of the product he consumed:

Sample DF:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

num_variables = 1000
rng = np.random.default_rng()

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' :  np.random.randint(1,999999999,num_variables),
    'date' : [np.random.choice(pd.date_range(datetime(2021,1,1),datetime(2022,12,31))) for i in range(num_variables)],
    'product' : [np.random.choice(['giftcards', 'afiliates']) for i in range(num_variables)],
    'brand' : [np.random.choice(['brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_4', 'brand_6']) for i in range(num_variables)],
    'gmv' : rng.random(num_variables) * 100,
    'revenue' : rng.random(num_variables) * 100,})

data = data.astype({'product':'category', 'brand':'category'})
base = data.groupby(['id', 'product']).aggregate({'product' : 'count'})
base = base.unstack()
```

Now I need to group clients by the "type" column and just count how much there are in each group.

first, apply the categorization function and its application :

```
def setup(row):
if row[('product', 'afiliates')] >= 1 and row[('product', 'giftcards')] == 0:
    return 'afiliates'
if row[('product', 'afiliates')] == 0 and row[('product', 'giftcards')] >= 1:
    return 'gift'
if row[('product', 'afiliates')] >= 1 and row[('product', 'giftcards')] >= 1:
    return 'both'
base['type'] = base.apply(setup, axis=1)
base.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

So far, so good. If I run an groupby.agg, I get these results:

```
results = base[['type','id']].groupby(['type'], dropna=False).agg('count')
```

[image: results after agg]

but if instead of agg I try an agregate, it does not work.

```
results = base[['type','id']].groupby(['type']).aggregate({'id': 'count'})

Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 2
      1 #results = base[['type','id']].groupby(['type'], dropna=False).agg('count')
----> 2 results = base[['type','id']].groupby(['type']).aggregate({'id': 'count'})

File c:\Users\fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py:894, in DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    891 func = maybe_mangle_lambdas(func)
    893 op = GroupByApply(self, func, args, kwargs)
--> 894 result = op.agg()
    895 if not is_dict_like(func) and result is not None:
    896     return result

File c:\Users\fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:169, in Apply.agg(self)
    166     return self.apply_str()
    168 if is_dict_like(arg):
--> 169     return self.agg_dict_like()
    170 elif is_list_like(arg):
    171     # we require a list, but not a 'str'
    172     return self.agg_list_like()

File c:\Users\fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:478, in Apply.agg_dict_like(self)
    475     selected_obj = obj._selected_obj
    476     selection = obj._selection
--> 478 arg = self.normalize_dictlike_arg("agg", selected_obj, arg)
...
    606 # eg. {'A' : ['mean']}, normalize all to
    607 # be list-likes
    608 # Cannot use func.values() because arg may be a Series

KeyError: "Column(s) ['id'] do not exist"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve made the same question on Pandas [Github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/50045).

They helped me, I will reproduce the answer here.

you can see how to access your columns using:

```
print(base.columns.tolist())
[('id', ''), ('product', 'afiliates'), ('product', 'giftcards'), ('type', '')]
```

When you have a MultiIndex for columns, you need to specify each level as a tuple. So you can do:

```
base[['type','id']].groupby(['type']).aggregate({('id', ''): 'count'})
```

Regarding the title of this issue - agg and aggregate are aliases, they do not behave differently.

I suppose there is a bit of an oddity here - why can you do base[['id']] but not specify {'id': ...} in agg? The reason is because column selection can return multiple columns (e.g. in the example here, base[['product']] returns a DataFrame with two columns), whereas agg must have one column and one column only. Thus, it is necessary to specify all levels in agg.